# Looking for a film about a girl who can predict the future in her imagination

Tags: identify-this-movie

About 5 years ago I was watching a movie at a party but during the movie I fell asleep. I forgot the title, so I hope someone can help me find it.

The movie was about a girl, who has deja vú all the time. She can predict the future in her imagination or in pictures.

An example:

The girl and her friends go to a theme park. She takes a picture of her boyfriend standing in front of a roller coaster. Once they get in the roller coaster, she gets her hand stuck in chewing gum. It starts moving and, at the top of the free fall, an accident happens and they die. This was all her imagination and they are in the roller coaster again, it hasn't started yet, but she touches the chewing gum. She freaks out and gets out of her seat.

She and her friend got off the roller coaster but her best friend and boyfriend are still on it and she starts screaming once she sees the picture she took. The roller coaster is crushing into her boyfriends head. The accident she imagined happens and all people in the roller coaster die.

Comment: Seems very close to plot of [final-destination-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination_3)

Answer (score 6):

The movie you're looking for seems to be one from the [Final Destination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination) series more specifically its the 3rd one you're looking for.

The first paragraph in the [movie's wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination_3) matches the description you've provided in your post.

> Wendy Christensen, a high school student, visits an amusement park with her boyfriend Jason Wise, best friend Carrie Dreyer, and Carrie's boyfriend Kevin Fischer for their senior class field trip. As they board the Devil's Flight roller coaster, Wendy has a premonition that the hydraulics securing the seats and roller coaster cars will fail, killing everyone on board. When she panics several people leave or are forced off the ride, including Kevin; best friends Ashley Fruend and Ashlyn Halperin, alumnus Frankie Cheeks, athlete Lewis Romero, and goths Ian McKinley and Erin Ulmen. As they leave they witness the roller coaster derail, killing the remaining passengers, including Jason and Carrie, leaving Wendy devastated.

Comment: Thank you so much!! <3 That is indeed the movie I was looking for :D

Comment: yw. if you think it answered your question mark the answer as accepted so it will be useful for anyone else searching it .